# How to send mail using socket C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, websocket, smtp

I'm using socket to send mail from my Gmail acc to my Gmail acc to avoid SSL and authentification, but I don't know if Gmail somehow blocks these ports for TLS (spam reasons) because I'm not receiving anything also spam folder is empty.

If somebody has experience with this topic I would be thankful.

```
int main() {

    cout << "send mail" << endl;

    char arr[] = "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com";
    char* ptrServer = arr;
    char arr0[] = "someaddress@gmail.com";
    char* ptrReceiver= arr0;
    char arr1[] = "someaddress@gmail.com";
    char* ptrSender = arr1;
    char arr2[] = "- Some Data -";
    char* ptrSubject = arr2; 
    char arr3[] = "Hello from the PC";
    char* ptrMessage = arr3;

    sendEmail(ptrServer, ptrReceiver, ptrSender, ptrSubject, ptrMessage);

    cin >> arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the function that I use for send mail (I dont know exactly what you need to send for TLS, I just send this sequention EHLO and STARTTLS)

```
void sendEmail(char * server, char * to, char * from, char * subject, char * message) {


    SOCKET sockfd;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    hostent* host;
    sockaddr_in dest;



    char szSmtpServerName[64] = "";
    int sent;
    char line[256];

    if (WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if ((host = gethostbyname(server)) != NULL) {
            memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
            memcpy(&(dest.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);

            dest.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
            dest.sin_port = htons(25);

            sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


            connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) & dest, sizeof(dest));


            strcpy_s(line, "EHLO\n"); 
            sent=send(sockfd, line, strlen(line),0);
            Sleep(500);

            strcpy_s(line, "STARTTLS\n");
            sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
            Sleep(500);

            strcpy_s(line, "MAIL FROM:<");
            strncat_s(line, from, strlen(from));
            strncat_s(line, ">\n", 3);
            sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
            Sleep(500);


            strcpy_s(line, "RCPT TO:<");
            strncat_s(line, to, strlen(to));
            strncat_s(line, ">\n", 3);
            sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
            Sleep(500);

            strcpy_s(line, "DATA\n");
            sent = (send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0));
            Sleep(500);


            strcpy_s(line, "To: ");
            strcat_s(line, to);
            strcat_s(line, "\n");
            strcat_s(line, "From: ");
            strcat_s(line, from);
            strcat_s(line, "\n");
            strcat_s(line, "Subject: ");
            strcat_s(line, subject);
            strcat_s(line, "\n");
            strcat_s(line, message);
            strcat_s(line, "\r\n.\r\n");
            sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
            Sleep(500);

            strcpy_s(line, "quit\n");
            sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
            Sleep(500);

        }

    }
    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    cout << "mail was sent" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full specification of SMTP [is a publicly available document](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). If you review these formal specifications for SMTP, you will easily identify a number of fundamental problems with the shown code.

1) After establishing a connection, the sender must wait for the server's initial greeting message. The shown code immediately sends the `EHLO` command, without waiting.

2) After sending the `EHLO` command, the sender must wait for the server's response, instead of waiting 500 milliseconds, and process the response.

3) The EHLO command may fail, since it's an extension; if so the sender must fallback to HELO. Unlikely, with modern SMTP servers, but something that a robust program must be prepared to handle.

4) In all cases, the server's response may indicate an error, and/or refusal to accept mail. The shown code fails to do any error checking, whatsoever.

5) After sending the `STARTTLS` command, the sender must wait for the server's response, and if the command succeeds, the sender must initiate TLS negotiation. The shown code fails to do that.

6) After TLS negotiation takes place, and an encrypted connection is established, the SMTP session restarts from the initial state, from the EHLO/HELO state, instead of `MAIL FROM`.

You cannot take any kind of easy shortcuts, like sleeping for some prescribed period of time, instead of properly handling server replies. This will not reliably work, over time. It might seem to work, once or twice, but will eventually break. That's a guarantee. You must properly, and fully, implement every part of SMTP, and implement it correctly.

Since you are using Microsoft Windows, you should find complete documentation on using TLS on MS-Windows in Microsoft's documentation. Obviously, this is a very large topic that's simply not going to be copied, verbatim, into this answer or any other answer on Stackoverflow. See Microsoft's documentation, on MSDN, or elsewhere, for further information.

These are all fairly complex, large, technical programming topics. You will not find a complete description of them reduced to a complete, one or a two paragraph answer on Stackoverflow, or any other public forum. The only thing that anyone will be able to tell you is to refer to technical documentation for a complete specification of how a particular protocol works. Knowing where to find and how to read technical documentation is something that every C++ developer needs to know how to do.

You will also very likely to find that MS-Windows may offer an SMTP client library that correctly and properly handles all aspects of SMTP, including TLS, without having your code to worry about it. And whether or not such SMTP client library is available, is something that you will be able to determine only after consulting Microsoft's technical documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! Its really very helpful for everyone who is trying to understand this topic.

Comment: I mean is there another command to start the negotiation or it is handled with some winsock functions?

Comment: @Itsmycode Winsock does not handle SSL/TLS at all. You need a separate library for that. You can use Microsoft's SChannel, or the open source OpenSSL, or any number of other libraries that are available.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "*You will also very likely to find that MS-Windows may offer an SMTP client library that correctly and properly handles all aspects of SMTP*" - **Windows** does not offer such a built-in library. Microsoft's .NET framework, on the other hand, does have an [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) class, but it has been deprecated in favor of 3rd party libraries.